# Show that $\mathbb{E}(T) = \sum\limits^\infty_{k=1}\mathbb{P}(T \geq k)$ for $T$ nonnegative integer valued and $E[T] < \infty$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let T be a non-negative integer-valued random variable with $\mathbb{E}(T) < \infty $. Prove that
$\mathbb{E}(T) = \sum^\infty_{k=1}\mathbb{P}(T \geq k)$.

Had a few attempts, haven't really got anywhere. I'm wondering as I'm typing this if proof by induction is a good way to go.

Edit: One major thing I forgot to add, am I correct in thinking that also, $\mathbb{E}(T) = \sum^\infty_{k=1}k\mathbb{P}(T = k)$?

Comment: This post itself could have served as a "mother post" to duplicates (it has ONE  such existing link). The current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845) has more duplicate-links (two) and and more other links. Please see the meta post on [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$T=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{T\geqslant k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot \mathbf 1_{T=k}$$