# Why is $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1 + \sum^\infty_{k=1}\mathbb{P}(X > k)$ true?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I'm working through a problem regarding expected values in Markov chains, and at some point it says:

> Recall from probability that if $X$ is a positive integer valued random variable, then $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1 + \sum^\infty_{k=1}\mathbb{P}(X > k)$.

I know that by definition $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_a a\mathbb{P}(X = a)$, but I can't see how the above equality follows from this, nor am I sure if this is how to approach the problem.

Comment: I think you need the assumption that $X$ takes *nonnegative* integer values also.

Comment: Your equation is not true. What if $X$ is the constant RV $0$?

Comment: I assume that I must have written the hypotheses incorrectly in that case, I'll make an edit.

Comment: @Jack Even that's not true. What if $X$ is the constant RV $0$?

Comment: @ZacharySelk: Oops. I was thinking about a slightly more general case in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values). In the case of OP, $X$ should be positive as you pointed out.

Comment: What is wrong with the proof on WP? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values

Comment: @Did I assume that's directed at me? It's just that it was for a slightly more general case. If you're asking why I couldn't read it myself, it's because I didn't know what to search to find it.

Comment: Yes, without @, comments are addressed to the OP. // More general? What would be more general here? // And see also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/660185/

Comment: @Did I mean that the case addressed in the wiki addressed a more general case than what I had asked - some comments (now deleted) raised issue with this and Jack had edited his answer in response to it. The question is now resolved with some really helpful answers from all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$aP(X = a) = P(X=a) + \dots + P(X = a)$ ($a$ times)

Now assuming $X$ takes only integer values $\ge 1$, you have

$$1 = P(X > 0) = P(X = 1) + \color{red}{ P(X = 2)} + \color{green}{P(X=3) }\dots$$
$$P(X > 1) = \color{red}{P(X = 2)} + \color{green}{P(X = 3) }+ \dots $$
$$P( X > 2) = \color{green}{P(X = 3)} + P(X = 4) +  \dots $$

and so on.

Summing everything on the LHS you get $ 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X > k)$, on the RHS you find $\sum_{a = 1}^\infty aP(X = a)$

Hence $$E[X] = \sum_{a = 1}^\infty aP(X = a) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X > k)$$

Comment: Wonderful, nice and easy! And coincidentally, the proof is in the same style as other proofs in the material.

Comment: @IrregularUser Happy to have helped :-)

Answer (score 6):

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable with distribution function $F_X$.  Then, by Fubini's Theorem, we have $$E[X]=\int_{[0,\infty)}\,x\,\text{d}F_X(x)=\int_{[0,\infty)}\,\int_{[0,\infty)}\,\chi_{[0,x)}(t)\,\text{d}t\,\text{d}F_X(x)=\int_{[0,\infty)}\,\int_{[0,\infty)}\,\chi_{[0,x)}(t)\,\text{d}F_X(x)\,\text{d}t\,,$$
where $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function on a set $E$.
That is,
$$E[X]=\int_{[0,\infty)}\,\int_{[0,\infty)}\,\chi_{(t,\infty)}(x)\,\text{d}F_X(x)\,\text{d}t=\int_{[0,\infty)}\,\text{Prob}(X> t)\,\text{d}t\,.$$
In particular, if $X$ is discrete, say, $X(\omega)\in\left\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\right\}$ for all $\omega$ with $0\leq x_1<x_2<\ldots$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\,x_n=\infty$ (this ordering doesn't always exist, for example, when the possible values of $X$ are in $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$), then
$$\begin{align}
E[X]&=\int_{[0,x_1)}\,\text{Prob}(X>t)\,\text{d}t+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\int_{[x_{i},x_{i+1})}\,\text{Prob}(X>t)\,\text{d}t
\\&=\int_{[0,x_1)}\,1\,\text{d}t+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\int_{[x_{i},x_{i+1})}\,\text{Prob}(X>x_{i})\,\text{d}t
\\
&=x_1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\left(x_{i+1}-x_i\right)\,\text{Prob}\left(X>x_{i}\right)\,.
\end{align}$$
If $\left\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\right\}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$, then we get $$E[X]=1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\text{Prob}(X>i)\,,$$ as required.  As Zachary Selk mentioned, if $\left\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\right\}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, then $$E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\,\text{Prob}(X>i)\,.$$

Answer (score 2):

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values) in Wikipedia
gives an answer to your question.

A slightly more general statement says the following:

> When a random variable $X$ takes only values in nonnegative integers, we can use the following formula for computing its expectation (even when the expectation is infinite):
>   $$
>  \operatorname{E}[X]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty P(X\geq i)=P(X\geq 1)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty P(X> i)\tag{*}
> $$
>   In the case when $X$ takes values in positive integers, one has $P(X\geq 1)=1$ in $(*)$.

Comment: Thanks for making the effort to correct your post (+1).

Comment: Indeed. Removed my downvote accordingly.

Comment: I didn't notice the nuances until I read @ZacharySelk's comment and I just pressed the "Post Your Answer" button too quick... Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Don't worry about it, any confusion was short lived and if anything, I learnt something about the slightly more general case, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting geometric proof for this proposition given in Section $5$ of *Probability and Measure* by *Patrick Billingsley*. I will copy the illuminating figure from this textbook:
[image]

Note that the equation to be proved can also be written as 
$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty P[X \geq x] dx. \tag{1} $$

For your special case, $x_i$s in the figure are integers $i$, but they can be any finitely many real numbers. To get a proof from the above picture, the author explains:

> There is for $(1)$ a simple geometric argument involving the "area over
>   the curve." If $p_i =P[X = x_i]$, the area of the shaded region in the figure is the sum 
>   $$p_1x_1 + \cdots +p_k x_k = E[X]$$ 
>   of the areas of the horizontal strips; it is also the integral of the height $P[X \geq x]$ of the region.