# Why does $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum^\infty_{r=0}\mathbb{P}(X > r)$?

Tags: probability, expectation

Why does $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum^\infty_{r=0}\mathbb{P}(X > r)$?

I understand if it was $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum^\infty_{r=0}r\cdot\mathbb{P}(X = r)$, but for this I don't understand why.

Comment: Google tail sum formula.

Comment: @probablyme Thanks for the name, but the proofs were too complicated for me.

Comment: @Surb Can you please give a complete proof? I can't understand how to get to $E[X]$ from there. I've tried $P(X > r) = \sum^\infty_{k=r+1}P(X=k) = \sum^\infty_{k=r+1}P(X=0) - \sum^\infty_{k=r}P(X=0)$ but I can't figure out how to get a $k$ in front...

Comment: @user341994: I completed my answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1795529/9464

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because,
$$P\{X>r\}=\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty P\{X=k\}.$$
under the assumption that $P\{X\in \mathbb N\}=1$.

**Added**

Therefore,
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty P\{X>r\}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \sum_{k=r+1}^\infty p\{X=k\}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{r=0}^{k-1}p\{X=k\}=\sum_{k=1}kp\{X=k\}=\mathbb E[X].$$

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer the question explicitly:

This only holds if $P(X \in \mathbb{N})=1$, a fact we use on the 3rd equality:

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}P(X > n)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}E[1_{X>n}]=E[\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}1_{X>n}]=
E[\sum^{X-1}_{n=0}1_{X>n}]=E[\sum^{X-1}_{n=0}1]=E[X]$

The second equation is due to Fubini, as $\sum$ is an integral with respect to the counting measure.