# An apparently easy game of chance

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

The game begins with $n$ coins.

- Every round we pay 1 dollar, toss all the $n$ coins, and remove the $T$ coins which landed in Tail.
- Then we start over with the remainder $n-T$ coins until there are no more coins.
- You receive a prize $P$ when the Game ends (All coins landed Tails in any of the throws)

The excercise is to find the fair price of the final prize $P$ given $n$ (price in which in long term both players do not lose or earn any money from playing)

For n = 1 I thought on:

| Coin toss | Probability | Total paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | $1/2$ | 1 |
| HT | $1/4$ | 2 |
| HHT | $1/8$ | 3 |
| HHHT | $1/16$ | 4 |
| HHHHT | $1/32$ | 5 |
| HHHHHT | $1/64$ | 6 |
| ... | ... | ... |

With $P(n=1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n}{2^n}) = 2$

So the Fair Prize of this game for $n=1$ is 2 dollars.

How can it be calculated for a higher amount of initial coins? lets say $n=2$ or $n=16$.

My thoughts until now are, for 2 coins, in the first toss:

| Coin results | probability | thoughts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (HH) | 1/4 | which I don't know how to proceed, because is recurrent, as with the 1 coin example |
| (HT) | 1/4 | the price of one coin |
| (TH) | 1/4 | same, price of one coin |
| (TT) | 1/4 | we finish the game, so you receive the prize. |

Any thoughts?

Clues on how to push this to higher dimensions?

Comment: The probability that a single coin comes up $T$ at least once in $m$ trials is $1-.5^m$.  Therefore the probability that the game ends in $m$ rounds or fewer is $(1-.5^m)^n$  You can then get the probability that it ends in exactly $m$ rounds by subtraction.

Comment: The analysis in the comment of @lulu, which did not occur to me, is more elegant than what *would* have been my first try, which might or might not have succeeded: recursion.  That is: $$E(n) = 1 + \left( ~\frac{1}{2^n} \times \sum_{i = 0}^n \left[ ~\binom{n}{i} \times E(n-i) ~\right] ~\right).$$

Comment: You may find helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755804/interested-in-a-closed-form-for-this-recursive-sequence/3755824#3755824 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361569/expected-flips-for-n-coins/1361582#1361582 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944546/toss-100-fair-coins-and-take-away-the-tails-toss-the-remaining-coins-and-take-a/3944658#3944658 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-i-i-d-geometric-random-variables https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923416/asymptotic-growth-of-sum-k-1n-frac-left-1-rightk1-binomnk1-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the amount of rounds at the end of the game.

Then $$P(X\le x) = \left(1- a^x\right)^n$$

for $a=\frac12$ (this is the same approach as @lulu's comment). Hence

$$P(X>x)= 1-P(X\le x) =  \sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j+1} \binom{n}{j} a^{xj}$$

We are interested in $E[X]$, [which is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798205/why-does-mathbbex-sum-infty-r-0-mathbbpx-r)

$$\begin{align}
E[X] &= \sum_{x=0}^\infty P(X>x)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j+1} \binom{n}{j}\sum_{x=0}^\infty  a^{xj} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j+1} \binom{n}{j} \frac{1}{1-a^j} \\
\end{align}
$$

I'm not sure if this can be further simplified.

PS: It seems not https://oeis.org/A158466
From the papers quoted there one can get some asymptotics.

A semiempirical approximation $E[X]\approx \log_2(n) +1.336 + {0.664}\frac{1}{n}$, quite precise for the full range $1\le n \le \infty$

Comment: Amazing answer. I tried the two approaches, the one provided by @lulu (Calculating the difference between each of the values of the probability of the game ending in $m$ rounds or fewer), and the one provided by you (with the sum from j=1 to n) and both converge numerically to basically the same results.

All of the steps are quite clear, but I don't get where the Sum is coming from. The one resulting from 1-P(X>x)
Could you develop more on this one? Thanks a lot!

(I also liked the semiempirical approximation ngl)

Comment: " I don't get where the Sum is coming from" The first one? It's just the Binomial theorem applied to the first equation.