# Expected Value Inequality - bounded by sums of probabilitys

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I have to show the following inequality:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P[Y>k] \leq E[Y] \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P[Y>k]$$
under the condition that Y is a non negative continuous random Variable.

My first idea was to rewrite the inequality using integrals, but then i end up having to integrate over a sum, which is nothing im particulary excited about.
Any Ideas on how i can do this?

Comment: This has been asked many times. See both the continuous and discrete cases in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795529/why-is-mathbbex-1-sum-infty-k-1-mathbbpx-k-true

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64186/9464

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $Y$ is nonnegative, then
$$E[Y] = \int Y \, dP = \int \int_0^\infty I\{x < Y\} \, dx \, dP = \int_0^\infty \int I\{x < Y\} \, dP \, dx = \int_0^\infty P(Y > x) \, dx$$

Now apply the standard comparison between integrals and sums.

Comment: are you - by any chance - talking about this one: $ \sum_{i \in I} f(i) = \int_I {f(x) #dx} $

Comment: No, that is not a valid equation. I am talking about a comparison between Riemann-integral and infinite sum.