# Expression of expected value for counting process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

In [this document](http://membres-timc.imag.fr/Olivier.Francois/processus.pdf) at page 20, one can read $M(t)$ as being defined as the expected value of $N_t$ where $N_t$ is the number of occurence of an event at time=t. As demonstration of the result, the author says:

$$E[N_t] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{P(N_t>n)}$$

I don't understand where it comes from. The expected value should be

$$E[N_t] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n P(N_t=n)}$$

How do you obtain the author's expression?

Comment: The other question has a link to WP where this result is proved.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/660185/6179

Comment: IMO, @user430501 has a nice intuitive answer...for what it is worth...

Comment: @PIe ...Which was already posted several times, sometimes with supporting figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like this. Let a = P(N = 1), b = P(N = 2), and c = P(N = 3) and the only values N can take on are (1,2,3). Thus, if we use the standard definition for the expected value, we get the following expression:

E[N] = (a) + (b + b) + (c + c + c)

We can represent this sum as a right triangle

a

b b

c c c

Under the standard way, we are adding these up "row-wise", but what if we added them "column-wise"?

That would be equivalent to E[N] = (a + b + c) + (b + c) + (c)

(a + b + c) = P(N > 0)

(b + c) = P(N > 1)

(c) = P(N > 2)

Which is the alternative expression for expectation we desired.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable with range $\mathbb{N}$. Then
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[X]
  &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n \mathbb{P}[X=n] \\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}[X=n] \\
  &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X=n] \\
  &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X \ge k] \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X > k]
\end{split}
$$

Comment: This is nice and clean!  Could someone explain the step from the second to the third equality?  I don't quite understand how we got to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X=n]$

Comment: @kdbanman think about the index pairs involved. The first sum has $(n,k)$ as follows: $(1,1), (1,2), \ldots (1,n), (2,1), (2,2), \ldots, (2,n), \ldots$. What the first sum connects row-first, the second does column first...

Answer (score 0):

Because...

$$E[X] = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} n P(X = n) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} P(X > n) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (1 - P(X \leq n)),$$

The continuous analog is

$$E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - F_{X}(x)) \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} R(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X>x) \, dx,$$

where $R(x)$ is the reliablity function and is defined by $R(x) = 1 - F(x)$.